# Erro ao referenciar valor de um objeto em outro objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, json, objetos

Tenho a seguinte variável com vários objetos dentro:

```js
const dados = {
  estudouNaFaculdadeAno: {
    metricas: {
      ano: [],
      invalido: {
        num: 0,
        palavras: []
      }
    }
  },
  estudouNaFaculdadeCurso: {
    metricas: {
      curso: {
        ads: 0,
        grh: 0,
        gpi: 0
      },
      invalido: {
        num: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num,
        palavras: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.palavras
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ao executar um `console.log(dados)` eu recebo o seguinte código de erro:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'dados' before initialization at dados.js:550`

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o pq disso? Como faço para ele referenciar sem ter esse problema?

PS.: esse arquivo dados.js contém somente a constante `dados` com os valores a serem lidos por outras funções que estão em outros arquivos .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está referenciando o objeto `dados` dentro dele mesmo. Irá resultar no erro porque a variável `dados` ainda não foi inicializada. Ao tentar construir o objeto, o JavaScript irá tentar buscar o valor de `dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num`, porém esse valor está dentro do próprio objeto que ainda está sendo construído, ou seja, ele ainda não foi inicializado.

Você pode usar um getter para retornar esses valores dentro do próprio objeto:

Em vez de:

```
invalido: {
   num: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num,
   palavras: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.palavras
}
```

Use:

```
get invalido(){
  return {
     num: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num,
     palavras: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.palavras
  }
}
```

Veja o resultado:

```js
const dados = {
  estudouNaFaculdadeAno: {
    metricas: {
      ano: [],
      invalido: {
        num: 0,
        palavras: []
      }
    }
  },
  estudouNaFaculdadeCurso: {
    metricas: {
      curso: {
        ads: 0,
        grh: 0,
        gpi: 0
      },
      get invalido(){
        return {
           num: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num,
           palavras: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.palavras
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(dados.estudouNaFaculdadeCurso.metricas.invalido);
```

Comment: Opa, você me deu uma luz e tanto @Sam ! Muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score -1):

Revise a estrutura que você está utilizando.
Há duas referências circulares no seu json:

num: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num,
palavras: dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.palavras

Insira valores JSON válidos, como por exemplo:

num: 1234,
palavras: "palavras jogadas ao vento!"

Então o valor para o caminho JSON dados.estudouNaFaculdadeAno.metricas.invalido.num será 1234.

Comment: Então, mas o q eu quero é justamente pegar um dado de outro objeto. Fazendo da forma q tu disse eu teria valores fixos no `num` e `palavras` do objeto `estudouNaFaculdadeCurso`